# Android Retrofit - how to override baseUrl

Tags: android, retrofit

In the retrofit adapter i have used a base Url for all my calls. so:

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Lets say the above is my code, all my calls now use that baseUrl.  But for one particular call, i want to change the base url, I dont want to create another rest adapter for this,as its just for testing locally. Can i change the end points in the interface possibly to not use the baseurl , or is there a annotation to supply my own base url ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can use the `@Url` annotation to provide the full complete url. E.G.

```
@GET
Call<GitHubUser> getUser(@Url String url);
```

Comment: i am using 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0' will it work, nowo it is saying it cant find that annotation. i dont see it in the docs:  http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.8.0/index.html?retrofit/http/package-tree.html

Comment: I am getting an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: \@Url cannot be used with \@GET URL (parameter #1)

Comment: @sativa it is hard to say what and why without seeing how you are using it

Comment: Like this (It's kotlin not java)

\@GET("api/1/route")
fun route(\@Url url: String = "https://myurl.com"): Observable<Route>

Comment: you are using it in wrong way. @URL wants the complete url to the endpoint. Is a way to override the base url you fed retrofit with. `\@GET fun route(\@Url url: String = "myurl.com/api/1/route"): Observable<Route>` is a valid option.

Answer (score 20):

In retrofi2 the path in @GET overrides the base URL.

```
 @GET("https://someurl/api/supermarkets")
 Observable<List<TechIndex>> getTechIndexList();
```

The request will be send to "someurl/api/.."  no matter what base url is.
Hope it helps